# How to create a FullScreen NSWindow which should show the dock but hide menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, dock

I'm new to OS X. I would like to to create a fullscreen NSWindow which should show the dock but hide menu bar like launchpad.

Comment: @sudha the edit suggested by you is adding nothing to the quality of the question..please consider it

Answer (score 1):

```
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [_window setCollectionBehavior:
   NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];

    [_window toggleFullScreen:self];

    [NSMenu setMenuBarVisible:NO];
}
```

Try above code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  [NSMenu setMenuBarVisible:NO] will hide both menubar and dock. Also I don't want to toggle between fullscreen and normal screen. I want my window should look exactly like launchpad.